# MenuItem is not closing after being clicked when containing ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have the following XAML for a MenuItem:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="CustomMenuItem"
         Command="{Binding Path=Command, Mode=OneWay}">
   <MenuItem.Header>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MenuContentControl"
                          Content="{Binding Path=Content, Mode=OneWay}"/>
   </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

The menu is rendered correctly and I can see the Command firing but the menu does not close afterwards, why is this and how can I make it close?

Comment: In cases like this try creating a small but complete piece of code (and paste it here) that can reproduce the issue, its impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: I created a test project and I have everything working.

Comment: Menu might not be getting the click.  I have some ContentPresenter content in a a ListBoxItem and the ListBox does not receive the click.  ListBox does get the click on direct controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `ContextMenu` closes on any click of menuItem.

But, however since you haven't posted more of your XAML code here. I suspect at top level or on this **MenuItem you must have set [StaysOpenOnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.staysopenonclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true**.

```
<MenuItem Header="submenuitem1"
          StaysOpenOnClick="true" 
          IsCheckable="true"/>
```

Remove that value if set or set that to false which is default value for all menu items.